# GeeksForGeeks practice: printing array bigger than its size in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Problem : https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/array-of-alternate-ve-and-ve-nos1401/1#

My code is added below. It runs perfectly well on my machine as well as when I `compile & run` on the GFG. But when I `submit` the code, it gives me error on the same input which was cleared in `compile & run`.

I have added the output of both `compile & run` and `submit`.

[image]

[image]

How Come it is printing the array bigger than its size?

```
#User function Template for python3
def updatePosIndex(array, pos_index,n,k):
    for index in range(pos_index+k,n):
        if array[index] >= 0:
            pos_index = index
            break
    return pos_index

def updateNegIndex(array, neg_index,n, k):
    for index in range(neg_index+k,n):
        if array[index] < 0:
            neg_index = index
            break
    return neg_index

def twoPointer(array,n):
    pos_index = updatePosIndex(array, 0, n, 0)
    neg_index = updateNegIndex(array, 0, n, 0)
    flag = 1
    for i in range(n):
        if flag == 1:
            if array[i] < 0:
                array[i], array[pos_index] = array[pos_index], array[i]
                neg_index = updateNegIndex(array, neg_index,n, 1)
            pos_index = updatePosIndex(array, pos_index,n, 1)
        elif flag == -1:
            if array[i] >= 0:
                array[i], array[neg_index] = array[neg_index], array[i]
                pos_index = updatePosIndex(array, pos_index,n, 1)
            neg_index = updateNegIndex(array, neg_index,n, 1)
        flag = flag*-1
    return array

class Solution:
    def rearrange(self,arr, n):
        arr = twoPointer(arr,n)
        arr = arr[:n]
        return arr

#{ 
#  Driver Code Starts
#Initial Template for Python 3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tc = int(input())
    while tc > 0:
        n = int(input())
        arr = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
        ob = Solution()
        ob.rearrange(arr, n)
        for x in arr:
            print(x, end=" ")
        tc -= 1

# } Driver Code Ends
```

Note: I don't want alternate solutions. I want to know why this problem exists and how to prevent it in future.

Comment: Explain your code?  What is `tc`?

Comment: @user202729--I believe tc stands for test cases (i.e. number of tests to be run).

Comment: I suspect it's not your fault and that they have a bug in the driver-code in the portion that prints the result: it prints all the use-cases on the same line... Unfortunately you're not allowed to edit the driver-part. So you can just open a ticket/bug and wait for them to respond.

Comment: @NirAlfasi Thanks for you answer! But, I already got message from my mentor that the solution was right and there is problem with their platform.

Comment: UPDATE: I opened a case in GFG yesterday and here's the response I got a few hours ago: "Hi, 
Thank you for bringing this to our attention. We have fixed the issue. Kindly refresh the page and then reset the IDE using the second button on the top right corner and submit your code again."  FYI

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

**First (Minor)** you must alter the `arr` list inside the `rearrange` method and there is no need to return any value. take a look at the driver code. there is no assignment there. so you only need to change the `arr` list inside the `rearrange` method.

**Second (Major)**, also there is a bug inside the `GeeksForGeeks` judge system. when the driver prints the output of the previous runs it won't clear the buffer and unfortunately the new input and old outputs merge together so the judge system misevaluates the results.

to overcome these problems I've changed the `Solution` class a bit:

```
Flag = False
class Solution:
    def rearrange(self,arr, n):
        global Flag
        twoPointer(arr,n)
        if Flag == True:
            print()
        else:
            Flag = True
```

now, your code passes the first test case successfully. but seems that it won't run correctly over the second result. but this is another issue.